# How to build stage based on code change with Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Let's assume that we have git repo with some code in it.

Now we want to build few docker containers with jenkisfile like this:

```
        stage('Building image 1') {
            steps{
                script {
                    'sh docker build -f 1'
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Building image 2') {
            steps{
                script {
                    'sh docker build -f 2'
                }
            }
        }
```

How can I trigger a build only on one stage based on change in some files.

With another words: Let's say that I have 2 files and I want to build stage 1 only `IF` file 1 have changes, or I want to build stage 2 only `IF` if file 2 is changed?

Comment: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/ look for changeset

Answer (score 3):

Resource: jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax look for changeset

Example would be something like this:

```
stage('Building image 1') {
    when {
        changeset "some_folder/some_file1"
    }
        steps{
            script {
                'sh docker build -f 1'
            }
        }
    }
stage('Building image 2') {
    when {
        changeset "some_folder/some_file2"
    }
    steps{
       script {
           'sh docker build -f 2'
        }
    }
}
```